# Concatenate URL link with Django variable

Tags: python, html, django

I would like to `concatenate` my url with a `Django variable` but I don't find a way to do that.

My url link looks like :

```
http://demoged.datasystems.fr/frontend.jsp?docID=
```

and I would like to add after `=` the following variable : `{{ids}}`

So I tried something like this :

```
<a href="http://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/frontend.jsp?docID=" + {{ids}} ">Link</a>
```

Have you an idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Try <a href="http://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/frontend.jsp?docID={{ ids }}">Link</a>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply render the value in the href.

```
<a href="http://demoged.datasystems.fr:8090/frontend.jsp?docID={{ids}}">Link</a>
```